# list.to_csv in pandas dataframe not working correctly due to a comma in a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im using list.to_csv to make a csv file from panda.dataframe. everything works great except if theres a comma in variables, it the one after comma would go to next column.
is there any way to fix this?

```
datalist = {'Owner/Occupant': ["andrew"],
            'Job Address': ["test, newyork"],
            'Buyer': ["andrew"],
            'Phone': ["12312341234"]}

data_list= pd.DataFrame(datalist)
data_list.to_csv('test.csv', sep = '\t')
```

and if i open test.csv it would look like this

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Define "not work" -- this is as much about what the default settings for the program you open the csv in as well. So - what program is supposed to open it correctly by default, are you willing to change the format of the output to make that happen?  Does quoting=1 produce an acceptable file and what does the reader think about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the csv reader (Excel, it looks like). Excel is going to make assumptions about delimiters.

Try opening the .csv file in a text editor (notepad), copy the whole thing, and paste it into Excel. Then use Excel's text-to-columns and be clear that the delimiter is tab instead of comma.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use `sep = '|'` then when you open your CSV you should be able to select the option of using the | as a delimiter. Excel > Data Tab > From Text/CSV > Select the created file > select | as delimiter

Answer (score 0):

when you're saving it with \t (tab) as a separator, then shouldn't you read it the same way i.e. as tab separator?

Alternately, you can try to use "," as a separator and using escapechar attribute of to_csv when writing to csv